# I have data in Sql table but id doesnt output the right characters from SQL Table

Tags: html, mysql, character-encoding, diacritics

I have a question , i have read all the possible answers but i don't find the solution.
i have data in mysql but when i select data from mysql and show it in html web page then it doesn't show german charcters correctly.
My code is:

```
    INSERT INTO `extra_ingredients` (`extra_Ingredient_Serial`, `extra_Ingredient_Category`, `extra_Ingredient_Sub`, `extra_Ingredient_Name`) VALUES  
(NULL, 'Pizza', '1', 'Sahnesauce'), 
(NULL, 'Pizza', '1', 'Dönerfleisch'), 
(NULL, 'Pizza', '1', 'Schafskäse');
```

[image: SQL DATA Table]

as you can see in the table data is shown correctly but when i select with query and output in html page it shows something line this.
[image: WEbPage Screenshot]

how can i resolve the issue .
any help will be appreciated.
Note I am using "UTF-8" in HTML page and    "utf8mb4_german2_ci" in HTML I have also tried with "utf8_german2_ci" , "utf8_unicode_ci".
i have entered data using sql query tab NOT using any HTML form, so i dont know why my data is encoded or decoded correctly while outputting in Html  page.

Update: when i entered data using HTML form then it outputs fine but it has saved not the same in mysql table
i entered "soße" from HTML table
in mysql table "soÃŸe"
in web page after selcting from mysql table "soße"

I dont want to enter data from HTML page because the data will be entered only once and with query i can insert all rows at once using query tab.

Comment: The gravy is not rotten, its encoding is.  `soÃŸe` is Mojobake; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  The "black diamond" case is also discussed there.  You probably have (or had) latin1 in the history of that database.  (The `COLLATION` is not relevant, jus the `CHARACTER SET`.)

Comment: See "black diamond" and "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored